# How i can make multi dimensional array from html table with php?

Tags: php, domdocument

How i can make multi dimensional array from html table with php where is a cell with rowspan 2

```
$table = "<table>
<tr><td class='root' rowspan='2'>Root</td><td class='key'>key1</td><td class='val'>val1</td></tr>
<tr><td class='key'>key2</td><td class='val'>val2</td></tr>
</table>";

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($table);
$classnameRoot = "root";
$classnameKey = "key";
$classnameVal = "val";
$a = new DOMXPath($doc);

$spansRoot = $a->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classnameRoot ')]");
$spansNfo = $a->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classnameKey ')]");
$spansTtl = $a->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classnameVal ')]");
```

I can not understand what should do next

Comment: Table has only 2 dimensions. Just do this in a loop: $array["rowX"]["columnX] = $value;

Comment: This question seems to be abandoned.  If you have found your own resolution, please post it as an answer so that SO readers can benefit.  If you still need a solution, please edit your question to provide additional information and hopefully someone (maybe even me) will help.  Alternatively, if you are no longer interested in receiving an answer, please delete this question.